# How do the rest of the modules access "Firebase" class, after we initialize using ```Firebase.initializeApp();``` in the entry point?

Tags: firebase, flutter, class, dart, initialization

So my app is working, but I want to understand what does the initialization actually do?
and why do we have access to a "Firebase" class only after we initialize?
in other words:
How do the rest of the modules access "Firebase" class, after we initialize using `Firebase.initializeApp();` in the entry point?

for reference, this is one approach of how we initialize:

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp()
);
}
```

My question is, how is the returned value of the initialized app stored? so that I can access it from any module?

Answer (score 1):

In your case (no application name provided), it initializes a new `FirebaseAppPlatform` for the default Firebase App and returns it as a `Future<FirebaseAppPlatform>`. This method should be called before any usage of FlutterFire plugins.

Thanks to that `FirebaseApp` instance, all the Firebase module can get access to the initialized Firebase Application. Example for Firestore: `FirebaseFirestore.instance`

Thanks to that initialization using `await`, you'll also get a synchronous getter for the `currentUser`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, my question is, how is the returned value of the initialized app stored? so that I can access it from any module?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Is `Firebase.app()` from `firebase_core` package what you are looking for?

Comment: I am trying to understand how it works, and how the rest of the app can access a value that is initialized only in the main file?

Comment: It uses a Singleton Pattern with a `static _instance` variable. Have a look at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/e0fc65362a4a60030680d89801875f0a4665d2d3/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase.dart

Comment: Okay, that is what I was looking for, thanks